# Facebook new permissions - Can't post video to user timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook came out with an update yesterday removing the permission **publish_actions**. That permission allowed me to publish a video to a user's profile or a page that they managed.

I figured out that **publish_to_groups** allows me to still publish videos to any group pages the user manages. But I cannot figure out how to publish to the user's on timeline. I tried **publish_video** but still I get the error **(#100) No permission to publish the video"**

```
$(document).on 'click', '#facebook_sign_in', (e) ->
e.preventDefault()
FB.login ((response) ->
  window.location = '/auth/facebook/callback' if response.authResponse
),
scope: 'email,publish_to_groups,publish_video,publish_pages,manage_pages,pages_show_list'
```

What permission do I need in order to publish videos to a user's timeline?

Comment: "or a page that they managed" - publish_pages would be used for that, not publish_actions. unless you wanted to post "as user", not "as page".

Comment: about publish_video: did you try with a page token on a page you manage? that permission is new, maybe it works for pages only.

Comment: @luschn I can post to a page/group that a user manages, I just need to post to a users timeline. Not sure what you mean page token. I send the access token like I normally do. Facebook even states that Buzzsprout can "Publish video to your timeline on your behalf" in the integrations setting section. But it doesn't work. Am i missing something?

Comment: Are you trying to publish a _live video_? Because that is the only thing `publish_video` permission allows for, as far as I can see. You can not use it to just upload “normal” videos.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe do you know what permission allows you to upload normal videos to a user's timeline?

Comment: Currently - none.

Comment: Yea that's so strange since you can post a live video to a user's timeline and a normal video to a group/page, but not a normal video to a user's timeline! Do you know if there are ever going to allow this capability? Also if you want, put that as an answer and ill mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got a confirmation from Facebook devs that uploading a video to a user's timeline is no longer supported in the API. Nor is it supported in the web version of the share dialog (the web version of the share dialog only posts links). It is supported for the iOS and Android versions of the share dialog.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android